# gson deserializing: Reference owner of nested object

Tags: java, json, nested, deserialization, gson

I want to write a custom deserializer for my Object, but in order to accomplish this, I need access to another part of the deserialized object. Imagine a JSON Object like this:

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "circle",
    "dependencies": {
        "donut": "e8ed7bbd8715de2f5a85930912fcf238"
    },
    "someReference": {
        "type": "Model",
        "refersTo": "donut"
    }
}
```

I know how to write an Adapter/Deserializer. I also know how to turn the "e8ed7bbd8715de2f5a85930912fcf238" into a Java object via former. What I don't and would like to know is how to turn my "donut" into "e8ed7bbd8715de2f5a85930912fcf238" or the ultimate Java object 'during' creation. This information lies in the field of the parent, as "someReference" corresponds to another Java object. So the top level class is an `Owner` with the fields:

```
public class Owner {
    public int id;

    public String name;

    public List<String, Resource> dependencies;

    public MyReference someReference;
}
```

`id`, `name`, `dependencies` all work so far.

So: How can I reference the parent object in a deserialization process? Is this even possible? What would be a workaround to what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a deserializer that does what you want (if I understood it of course). The only difference respect to what you asked is that I do not know what do you mean by `Reference`, so I used `String` instead. But I think you can easily adapt my code.

My Owner definition:

```
package stackoverflow.questions.q23718183;

import java.util.*;

public class Owner {
    public int id;

    public String name;

    public Map<String, String> dependencies;

    public MyReference someReference;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Owner [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", dependencies=" + dependencies + ", someReference=" + someReference + "]";
    }

    public static class MyReference {
        String type;
        String refersTo;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "MyReference [type=" + type + ", refersTo=" + refersTo + "]";
        }

    }

}
```

My deserializer:

```
package stackoverflow.questions.q23718183;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.*;

import com.google.gson.*;
import com.google.gson.stream.*;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

public class OwnerDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Owner> {

    @Override
    public Owner deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        if (json == null)
            return null;
        else {
            Owner owner = new Owner();
            JsonObject jo = json.getAsJsonObject();

            owner.id = jo.get("id").getAsInt();
            owner.name = jo.get("name").getAsString();

            TypeToken<Map<String, String>> mapType = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>() {};
            owner.dependencies = context.deserialize(jo.get("dependencies"), mapType.getType());

            Owner.MyReference reference = new Owner.MyReference();
            JsonObject jo2 = jo.get("someReference").getAsJsonObject();
            reference.type = jo2.get("type").getAsString();
            reference.refersTo = owner.dependencies.get(jo2.get("refersTo").getAsString());

            owner.someReference = reference;

            return owner;
        }
    }
}
```

My test code:

```
package stackoverflow.questions.q23718183;

import com.google.gson.*;

public class Q23718183 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = " {                                                          "+
                "    \"id\": 2,                                                 "+
                "    \"name\": \"circle\",                                      "+
                "    \"dependencies\": {                                        "+
                "        \"donut\": \"e8ed7bbd8715de2f5a85930912fcf238\"        "+
                "    },                                                         "+
                "    \"someReference\": {                                       "+
                "        \"type\": \"Model\",                                   "+
                "        \"refersTo\": \"donut\"                                "+
                "    } "+
                "}";

        GsonBuilder b = new GsonBuilder();
        b.registerTypeAdapter(Owner.class, new OwnerDeserializer());
        Gson g = b.create();

        Owner o = g.fromJson(s, Owner.class);

        System.out.println(o);


    }

}
```

and this is the result:

```
Owner [id=2, name=circle, dependencies={donut=e8ed7bbd8715de2f5a85930912fcf238}, someReference=MyReference [type=Model, refersTo=e8ed7bbd8715de2f5a85930912fcf238]]
```

As you can see, `donut` was substituted by its value into `dependencies` node.

Comment: Nice! It's too bad though since I didn't want to fumble in the OwnerDeserializer to accomplish this. I would have rather liked a MyReferenceDeserializer that gets an Owner as reference (or simply a JsonTree of the current "context" it is in). Something like `context.getParentNode().get("dependencies").get("donut")` I guess I have no other choice then.